# I'm developing an Android food ordering app, what software do I use to send the order to another device?

Tags: android, database

I'm making a project and I need to find a way to submit a food order to another device, like McDonald's does. Like when a customer chooses their order and they submit it to the kitchen for the food to be prepared.

I already have a functioning android app where you can select what food you want and the price and quantity add up correctly. All I need to do now is send this order info to another device which will act like the kitchen. The order will be viewable from that device. How can I achieve this? What software will I need to use? I've used android studio to make the food app.

I'm a beginner to programming, so I'm no expert. I've been told to use a database, something like Firebase.

Comment: Sounds like you need an HTTP RESTful API for communication (e.g `http://kitchen/order.php?tabel=3&item_1="big mac"&item_2="coke"`). A database might be used to record orders waiting to be cooked, and also sales. As you are new, expect this to take you a few months

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to communicate via the network, but there are many ways to do this.

You could include mysql library and connect directly to a database which both devices have access.

Send data to a web server.

However, one major thing that shouldn't be over looked is security.

Most android devices don't have a network jack.  Therefore they have to use wi-fi which has its own set of security issues.  So you need at least WPA2 or WPA3 (if it has been released yet) just to secure the initial connection.

Then you need TLS 1.2 or greater to secure communications over wifi.

Then you need to secure the receiving computer which I will designate as the server.  The server has to have a whole set of security in place to prevent it from being hacked or sent bad data.

Also more security including having the APP require a username/password so that I can't make a fake order and spam your system with fake orders.

The usernames/passwords need to be audited and monitor and changed.

If you intend to accept credit cards even more security measure will have to be put in place to meet there requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating the frontend. Then use your website as a blueprint to design your backend. The second year after you finish with it jump into a cross mobile platform technology like Cordova to create the portable apps. If you have questions in the process S.O is here.